# In apex how to know the whether a batch is schedule or it's running?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, developer

I want to know the status of a batch like whether it is schedule or it's running

Answer (score 0):

You can query the [ApexAsyncJob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) object to determine the status of a Batch job. You'll need to know the Job ID (obtained when you call Database.executeBatch or System.scheduleBatch).